# office activation with kms fails (ERROR CODE: 0x80070005)

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-registry, software-activation

I tried to activate my office with a persnoak working kms of mine.

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16>cscript ospp.vbs /act
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

---Processing--------------------------
---------------------------------------
Installed product key detected - attempting to activate the following product:
SKU ID: 85dd8b5f-eaa4-4af3-a628-cce9e77c9a03
LICENSE NAME: Office 19, Office19ProPlus2019VL_KMS_Client_AE edition
LICENSE DESCRIPTION: Office 19, VOLUME_KMSCLIENT channel
Last 5 characters of installed product key: 6MWKP
ERROR CODE: 0x80070005
ERROR DESCRIPTION: Run the following: cscript ospp.vbs /ddescr:0x80070005
NOTICE: A KB article has been detected for activation failure: 0x80070005
FOR MORE INFORMATION PLEASE VISIT: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2870357#Error0x80070005
---------------------------------------
---------------------------------------
---Exiting-----------------------------
```

I checked in the web and I tried to change the key's permission in safe mode:

```
Computer\HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-20
```

I tried to enable network service full control and checked the option to change all the subkeys.
and I get the error that registry editor cannot set security in the key selected , or some of its subkeys.

does anyone have a clue how to solve this issue? the office activation fails.

Comment: KMS has a minimum number of clients that are required before activation is possible do you meet that minimum?  Do you actually have a KMS or your using one of those KMS blockers

Comment: Microsoft's Enterprise Support is excellent. Give them a ring, they'll have you back up & running inside 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

For me, a very simple solution was, `run KMS as administrator`.

I installed new a windows before I came to this solution. I thought my windows and Word are having some KMS clash.

I hope someone try the `run as administrator` option before wasting too much time.

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be in the Microsoft article
[Resolve Windows activation error codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-server/get-started/activation-error-codes#0x80070005-access-denied):

> ## 0x80070005 Access denied
>
> The full text of this error message resembles the following:
>
> ```
> Access denied. The requested action requires elevated privileges.
> ```
>
> **Possible cause**
>
> *User Account Control (UAC) prohibits activation processes from running
> in a non-elevated Command Prompt window*.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Run slmgr.vbs from an elevated command prompt. To do this, on the
> Start menu, right-click cmd.exe, and then select Run as administrator.

In your case, run the Office activation as Administrator, and it might work
this time.